# "Live updates" when training a machine learning model in r shiny

Tags: r, machine-learning, shiny, r-markdown, mxnet

I am currently developing an user interface based on R markdown and shiny to make it easy to execute a machine learning training process for other users not proficient in R. This training process is done by a custom built function around the R package *mxnet* and gives status updates like the training error or what packages are loaded with the `message()` function directly to the console, when run in a "normal" R script. However, when running this app in R markdown nothing is printed to the browser. The following script shows a minimal reproducible example (with the training process replaced with an easy "dummy" function):

````
---
title: "Training of a Neural Network"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r start_training, echo=F}
inputPanel(
  actionButton("button_start_training", "Start training")
)
```

```{r dummy_function, echo=F}
dummy_function <- function(){
  for(i in 1:5){
    message(paste0("Test: "),i)
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
  }
}
```

```{r actual_training, echo=F}
event_training = eventReactive(input$button_start_training,{

  dummy_function()

})

renderPrint({
          event_training()

          })
```
````

The console output from `dummy_function()` is not displayed in the browser, but only in the console. If `message()` is replaced by `print()` something *is* displayed in the result, but only *after* the function is completed and not *"live"*. Because the actual training process takes a few hours, I would like to give these updates as they would occur in the console. Furthermore, replacing `message()` by `print()` could cause some issues since things like the training error are returned inside the mxnet training process as a message and not as a print (if I understood it correctly).

So, this boils down to two questions:

1. Is there a way to make `renderPrint()` print output as soons as it appears?
2. Is there a way to make `renderPrint()` use output generated by `message()` instead of `print()`?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use `withCallingHandlers` in combination with the `shinyjs` package (https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs). Using this, you can change the inner HTML of an element on the page, which shows immediately. Starting with an empty element, you can add a log to the element each time the function calls `message`, as follows:

```
dummy_function <- function(){
  for(i in 1:5){
    message(paste0("Test: "),i)
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
  }

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    actionButton("button_start_training", "Start training"),
    textOutput("logs")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$button_start_training, {
      withCallingHandlers({
        shinyjs::html("logs", "")
        dummy_function()
      },
        message = function(m) {
          shinyjs::html(id = "logs", html = m$message, add = TRUE)
      })
    })
  }
))
```